# ID3 and J48 using Weka

Tags: weka, id3

I am using weka to analyse data sets using id3 and j48 trees. However, the id3 classification doesn't allow you to graphically see the tree. Can the pruning for the j48 tree be turned off to obtain an id3?

Comment: Could you clarify on an example why an unpruned J48 tree is different from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Weka Javadoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html)

> Valid options are:
>
> ```
> -U
> Use unpruned tree.
> ```

So I think that answers your question.

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't come like an ID3, infact it just comes as a pruned tree

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean the option still gives you a pruned tree?

Comment: yes I thinks because J48 is like C4.5 so it does some kind of pruning. I need it to be like an id3 - no pruning at all

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. If you specify the "-U" option, the J48 is NOT pruned. I just looked at the source code to confirm this.